# Solr facets result not getting in csv format

Tags: solr

```
<div id="barcat"></div>
<!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->

<script>
    Plotly.d3.json('http://192.168.2.11:8983/solr/first_csv_solr/select?facet.field=categories&facet=on&q=*:*&facet.pivot=categories&wt=json&omitHeader=true', function (err, rows) {

        function unpack(rows, key) {
            return rows.map(function (row) { return row[key]; });
        }
        var data = [{
            x: unpack(rows, 'value'),
            y: unpack(rows, 'count'),


            type: 'bar',
            marker: {
                color: 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                opacity: 0.6,
                line: {
                    color: 'rgb(8,48,107)',
                    width: 0.5
                }
            }
        }];

        console.log("data")

        var layout = {
            height: 500,
            width: 600,

            // color: 'rgb(31,119,180)'
        }

        Plotly.newPlot('barcat', data, layout);
    })



</script>
```

I am getting the counts of factes but when i try to convert in csv it show only relevent column name. I want response as csv so i can connect in d3.js .
even i try to convert in json also but it not showing in standard json format.because it show header in json response

```
http://IP:8983/solr/first_csv_solr/select?facet.field=categories&facet=on&q=*:*&facet.pivot=categories&wt=json&omitHeader=true
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the "header" being shown in JSON format? How are you trying to connect it to d3.js?

Comment: hello i want to remove this response header.{
  "response":{"numFound":2592,"start":0,"docs":[

Comment: That's not really a header, but any reason why you can't do that when you consume the result in d3.js by referring directly to the subobject that you want?

Comment: Actually d3.js take only csv else json link.And when i got the count in categories field but when i do wt=csv it show only column name not facets count.Is it possible to convert facets result in csv response.

Comment: Yes, but d3js fully supports using a subsection of the JSON response. Add your D3JS code to the question and what's not working - the callback given to `d3.json` allows you to filter the data and set the domain for d3 if necessary.

Comment: Please add any code inline - and not as a downscaled screenshot. It's very hard to read, not searchable and impossible to grasp for people using screenreaders. Also, wouldn't something like `rows = rows.response.<..etc ..>` strip of the header you don't want?

Comment: Here is my way to acces d3.solr connect:Please check and let me know what are the change i need in this

Comment: Did you try what I wrote at the end of my comment? i.e. reassigning rows to be a reference to the deep location in the json array returned from Solr?